# Что означает @$ в php

Tags: php

Друзья, только сильно не пинайте!

Что означает эта запись **@$** ?

Пример кода:

```
@$sn = implode(";",$ret["name"]);
@$smt = implode(";",$ret["type"]);
@$smc = implode(";",$ret["code"]);
```

Comment: @ua6xh спасибо огромное :) это не мой код, вот пытаюсь воткнуть в процесс домнятины!

Comment: https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1.0-9/1505092_10202347492663592_6470165464951839859_n.jpg   я очень нехороший =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Оператор управления ошибками](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). Если вы будите использовать такой способ подавления ошибок, то всю ответственность за дебаг берите на себя, так как это будет анальная кара, когда скрипт будет падать и не выдавать никаких ошибок, а таких мест с "@" в коде будет много. Лучше управлять ошибками глобально.